# Connecting Ammeter and Voltmeter in the circuit

Tags: electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, potential-energy, voltage

I am unable to comprehend why ammeter is connected in series and voltmeter in parallel in a circuit. My book doesn't give any explanation about it nor am I able to understand it from the internet. Can someone please explain this to me (a beginner).

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/circuits-topic/circuits-resistance/v/voltmeters-and-ammeters

Comment: http://bit.ly/2dOjxzL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to see it might be this:

**Voltmeter**: needs to measure a potential difference, so you need to hook its ends to the two points which voltage you want to measure. This means you need to put it in parallel.

**Ammeter**: needs to measure a current, so you need to put it somewhere where all the current you want to measure will pass through it. This means you need to put it inside the circuit and thus in series.

Answer (score 0):

Current pass through a conductor, while voltage is applied across is. Ammeter measures and detects current that pass though the conductor, so the current need to pass though it, which is why it's connected in series. On the there hand, voltmeter as to be connected across the conductor, or the 2 points between which the potential difference, or the voltage is aimed to be measured. Hence it's connected in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

An ammeter measures current.   Current means the flow of some conserved
quantity, like water under a bridge.   The ammeter in series with a mystery component is delivering all of the current into an electrical terminal of the mystery component, so we expect the current in the ammeter to match the current in the mystery component.

If you stop calling the device an ammeter, and call it instead a current meter,
that should clarify the situation.  The ammeter measures the current through the ammeter, which (by virtue of the series connection) establishes identical current through the mystery component.  It has to be identical, because (like a bridge)
the current doesn't vanish into the bridge, all that water eventually comes out
the other side.  Current into ammeter terminal 1 comes out ammeter terminal 2.

Conversely, a voltmeter measures potential.  To make a hypothetical current
of water flow under the bridge, it is necessary that the
water level upstream of the bridge be slightly higher than the water level
downstream.  That height difference means a gravitational potential difference.

So, a potential meter needs to probe the water level both upstream and downstream
to know what the difference is, that keeps the water flowing.  To do this,
a potential meter must connect to the stream both upstream and downstream,
around the bridge.  Similarly, the electrical potential on
two terminals of the device-under-test must be connected to a voltmeter in
order to determine the potential difference, the voltage.  Connecting a
two-terminal voltmeter
on both sides of a two-terminal device, is a parallel connection.